# Rolling list that starts over

Tags: c#

So I have `10` persons.
I have `12` houses.

Every person shall go into the house in an order
Fx.

- House 1 - First person enters...then second....third ....unitl list is done
- House 2 - Second person enters, third, fortyh.....and lastly nr 1
- House 11 - First person enters...then second....third ....unitl list is done

How can I do this with some algortim that it starts over. I dont really know how to even start it or what to use.

This is for C#

Shall I use

```
Array [] []

house 1 - person 1
house 2 - person 2
house 3 - person 3
house 4 - person 4
house 5 - person 5
house 6 - person 6
house 7 - person 7
house 8 - person 8
house 9 - person 9
house 10 - person 10
house 11 - person 1
house 12 - person 2
```

Comment: Where does house 11 and 12 come from? what have you tried?

Comment: sorry should be 12 house. Correctd. Thx

Comment: Try modulo arithmetics, compute remainder, `%`; for given house number (say, `12`), person's number will be `1 + (house_number - 1) % persons`, e.g. `1 + (12 - 1) % 10 == 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *modulo arithmetics*. If we have `persons` in total (say, `10`), for a given `house` number (e.g. `12`) we can compute corresponding `person` number as

```
 int person = 1 + (house - 1) % persons;
```

where `%` is *remainder*. E.g. for `persons == 10` and `house == 12`

```
 person = 1 + (12 - 1) % 10 == 2
```

**Demo**

```
Func<int, int, int> person = (house, persons) => 1 + (house - 1) % persons;

int personsInTotal = 10;
int housesInTotal = 14;

var report = Enumerable
  .Range(1, housesInTotal)
  .Select(house => $"house {house} - person {person(house, personsInTotal)}");

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, report));
```

**Outcome:**

```
house 1 - person 1
house 2 - person 2
house 3 - person 3
house 4 - person 4
house 5 - person 5
house 6 - person 6
house 7 - person 7
house 8 - person 8
house 9 - person 9
house 10 - person 10
house 11 - person 1
house 12 - person 2
house 13 - person 3
house 14 - person 4
```